# CoTURN server stops after some time

Tags: linux, ubuntu, webrtc, turn, coturn

I've installed CoTURN on Ubuntu 16.04 server. I'm starting the TURN server with the below command:

turnserver -a -o -v -n --cert /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem --pkey /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem -u username:password -r "mydomain.com"

I check with Trickle ice and it works fine. But after some random time (typically in days) it stops working/shuts down.

Is there any way to run it forever or at least get an email if the service stops?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you solved the issue? In my case, the server shown active even though it wasn't working

Comment: Yes, now I'm using PM2 and it works fine.

Comment: You must check the configuration and allow the required ports from FW.

Answer (score 1):

I use the NPM tool called PM2 for that. If the service goes down, you can get notifications. Monit can do that - and also restart if necessary.

1. npm i pm2
2. pm2 start turnserver
3. sudo apt install monit
4. nano /etc/monit/monitrc

Here you can find examples how to enable a specific service. In your case it's the turnserver.

[Config](https://www.linuxcloudvps.com/blog/how-to-monitor-and-restart-services-with-monit/)

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm wondering if PM2 alone is capable of restarting the service if it goes down?